# JQuery: Colocar cada caracter de un string a un <span>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo muchos botones, con dos clases diferentes, los cuales tienen una transición que parte a través de separar el texto de los mismos letra por letra y colocar cada una en un span.

Para explicarlo mejor, tengo estos tres botones:

```
<a href="#" class="button">Sign up</a>
<a href="#" class="button">Get started</a>
<a href="#" class="button2">Continue</a>
```

Con esta funcion en JavaScript logré lo que quería:

```
(function() {
  var elems, button, i, span = "";
  elems = document.querySelectorAll('.button').length;
    for (j = 0; j < elems; j++)
    {
        button = document.querySelectorAll(".button")[j];
        let span = "<div>";
        for (i = 0; i < button.innerText.length; i++)
        {
            span += "<span>";
            if (button.innerText[i] !== " ")
            {
              span += button.innerText[i];
            }
            else
            {
              span += "&nbsp";
            }
            span += "</span>";
        }
        span += "</div>";
        button.innerHTML = span;
    }
}());
```

Pero sucede que debido a que tienen la misma clase "button", el texto concatenado del primer botón ("Sign up") se suma al siguiente y se ve así: "Sign up Get started".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haciendo un console.log(button.innerHTML); dentro del primer foreach obtuve esto:

```
<div>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>i</span>
    <span>g</span>
    <span>n</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>u</span>
    <span>p</span>
</div>
```

En el segundo botón se concatena todo así:

```
<div>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>i</span>
    <span>g</span>
    <span>n</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>u</span>
    <span>p</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>G</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>t</span>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <span>s</span>
    <span>t</span>
    <span>a</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>t</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>d</span>
</div>
```

La idea es que cada botón tenga su texto aparte con el fin de poder hacer la transición que les comento, que de verdad no viene al caso acá ya que es por css y al tener ambos textos de los botones correctamente este funciona perfecto.

Tambien, el tercer botón que tiene el texto "Continue" y la clase "button2" lo necesito hacer con la misma función pero tampoco tengo la idea de como reutilizar el código para cualquier clase de botón que tengo en el proyecto.

Llevo horas tratando de resolverle, me recomendaron cambiar a JQuery pero la verdad necesito ayuda con ello... apenas estoy comenzando con JavaScript.

Gracias.

Comment: En vez de inicializar la variable, estás concatenado `span += "<div>";`, debiendo ser `let span = "<div>";`

Comment: Excelente... ahora si me funciona. Y si por ejemplo tengo otro botón con la clase "button2" y quiero reutilizar ese código se puede o que me recomiendas? creo una función nueva para ese u otros botones que tengo?... ya que en varios botones con estilos diferentes necesito colocarles esa transición

Comment: Crea una función donde envíes la clase como parámetro y coloca ahí dentro tu código actual.

Comment: Guau! me podrías orientar para ello? es que de verdad entiendo poco la lógica de JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea la función para aplicar los cambios y, cuando se cargue el DOM, ejecútala, enviando como parámetro la clase de los elementos que quieres modificar:

```js
(function() {
    a2span('.button');
    a2span('.button2');
}());

function a2span(clase) {
    document.querySelectorAll(clase).forEach(button => {
        let text = button.innerText;
        let span = "<div>";
        for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++)
        {
            span += "<span>";
            if (text[i] !== " ")
            {
              span += text[i];
            }
            else
            {
              span += "&nbsp";
            }
            span += "</span>";
        }
        span += "</div>";
        button.innerHTML = span;
    });
}
```

```css
.button, .button2 {
    display:inline-block;
    color:#fff;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.button { background:#6ad; }
.button2 { background:#f60; }
.button span, .button2 span {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">Sign up</a>
<a href="#" class="button">Get started</a>

<a href="#" class="button2">Botón 2</a>
<a href="#" class="button2">Otro botón 2</a>
```

En lugar de obtener primero los elementos, recorrer con un ciclo y crear variables intermedias, puedes hacer todo en una misma línea:

- `document.querySelectorAll(clase)` es para obtener todos los elementos por la clase especificada
- `.forEach(button => { ... })` recorre los elementos y crea la variable `button` para usarla dentro de la [función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions)
- Dentro, creas una variable `text` con el contenido del elemento y es la que usas para el ciclo donde agregas los *span*

Comment: Amigo, excelente... así me voy orientando mejor y aprendiendo, pues lógica tengo pero me he enfrascado en php y Laravel tanto que uno se ciega ante otros conocimientos. De verdad mil gracias!!!

Comment: @roberthung, por favor edita la pregunta para quitar el `+=` y agregar que quieres hacerlo con 2 o más clases, para que no termine cerrada.

Comment: Listo... ya la edite... Tienes razón, tenia que colocar que queria reutilizar el código en la misma pregunta